# ScrollPane table not aligning acordingly

Tags: java, libgdx, scrollpane

I have a `ScrollPane` named `options`, and 4 tables named: `changeOptions`, `settingNames`, `backAndApply`, `overlay`. I have placed the first two tables inside the `overlay` table, and then added the `overlay` table into the `ScrollPane`. My problem is when I try to align the table `settingNames` to the left of `overlay`, it doesn't align.  Same goes for `changeOptions`. I activated debug, and the two tables are just pressed against each other.

This is my code:

```
/** Setting up a lot of variables before this, and adding them to their respected table.*/   
overlay.add(settingNames).left();
overlay.add(changeOptions).right();
options = new ScrollPane(overlay, scrollStyleSkin);
overlay.setWidth(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() - options.getScrollBarWidth());
cntStage.addActor(backAndApply);
options.setFadeScrollBars(false);
options.setBounds(
        0,
        (white.getBounds("|").height * 2),
        Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),
        (Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2 - (white.getBounds("|").height * 2)));
overlay.debug();
```

If I am not doing this correctly, please tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you can align left and right in the same row. Instead you might need to call something like this: `overlay.add(labelTitle).align(Align.left).padLeft(-Gdx.graphics.getWidth()).padTop(Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/25);` and set correct padding for adding the second table or try calling `overlay.row()` and having it align on the next row with negative padding. This is all I can think of right now without seeing exactly what you mean but maybe it'll help you get some more ideas.

Comment: Thank you, the first thing you said to call was right, I just had to play around with the padLeft size.